# Animate CALayer's borderColor using CABasicAnimation in a UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, uibutton, cabasicanimation

I have created a subclass of `UIButton` so that I may obtain a reusable custom appearance, including specifying the button layer's border corner. This is working great. I now want to add simple animation to indicate the highlighted state of the button. I need to animate the transition from one border color to another, which will occur when the user touches down on the button, then when they release, it needs to animate back to the original border color.

Desired behavior: the button's border starts out red when not highlighted. When the user touches and holds the button it changes to the highlighted state causing the border color to animate to blue. The user then slides their finger out of the button's bounds to cause the highlighted state to change (to unhighlighted), causing the animation to occur and revert the border color to red. If the user slides their finger back into the bounds, the button becomes highlighted, causing the border to animate to blue.

In my attempt to obtain that behavior, I implemented `setHighlighted` where I perform a `CABasicAnimation` based on the new `highlighted` boolean value. This does work when you tap and hold on the button - the border color transition animates. The problem is it does not animate upon button release. If I slide my finger off the button, the border color instantly reverts to red. I expected it to fade into red from blue. It's as if I did not specify any animation for the unhighlighted state. Also, if you tap and hold on the button then slide your finger inside the button's frame, the animation is instantly completed - it instantly jumps to blue. The only way I can get it to animate over 2 seconds as expected is to hold on the button without moving at all (easy to do in simulator, difficult on a real device). It should always nicely animate between states, never instantly jump in color changes.

My question is: How can I animate a button's `CALayer`'s `borderColor` in the button subclass, for transitions to/from the highlighted/unhighlighted states?

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted) {
        [self highlight];
    } else {
        [self unhighlight];
    }
}

- (void)highlight {
    UIColor *currentLayerColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithCGColor:self.layer.borderColor];
    UIColor *newLayerColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CABasicAnimation *color = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
    color.fromValue = (__bridge id)currentLayerColor.CGColor;
    color.toValue   = (__bridge id)newLayerColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.borderColor = newLayerColor.CGColor;

    color.duration = 2.0;
    [self.layer addAnimation:color forKey:nil];
}

- (void)unhighlight {
    UIColor *currentLayerColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithCGColor:self.layer.borderColor];
    UIColor *newLayerColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CABasicAnimation *color = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
    color.fromValue = (__bridge id)currentLayerColor.CGColor;
    color.toValue   = (__bridge id)newLayerColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.borderColor = newLayerColor.CGColor;

    color.duration = 2.0;
    [self.layer addAnimation:color forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: If you want to see the highlight animation followed by the unhighlight one regardless of how long you touch the button, you need to change the way you call those methods. You should call the highlight animation on touchDown, and call the unhighlight animation from the delegate method  `animationDidStop:finished:`

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, but that's not the desired behavior - I will update the question to clarify the effect I'm after here